# .before method adds unexpected close tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I have a table in my markup on which I want to add some divs before and efter like this:

```
<div class="widebox">
<div class="widebox-header">Opret/rediger bruger</div>
<div class="widebox-middle">
<table id="Table3"></table>
</div>
<div class="widebox-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do this with jQuery, like this:

```
$('#Table3').before('<div class="widebox"><div class="widebox-header">Opret/rediger bruger</div><div class="widebox-middle">');
$('#Table3').after('</div><div class="widebox-bottom"></div></div>');
```

However this is what renders out, the method seems to close my opening divs:

```
<div class="widebox">
    <div class="widebox-header">Opret/rediger bruger</div>
    <div class="widebox-middle"></div></div><!-- unexpected close divs -->
    <table id="Table3"></table>
<div class="widebox-bottom"></div>
```

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

before() and after() automatically close elements. Why don't try you use wrap() to insert widebox-middle around table?

```
$('#Table3').wrap('<div class="widebox-middle" />');
$('.widebox-middle').wrap('<div class="widebox" />');
$('.widebox-middle').before('<div class="widebox-header">Opret/rediger bruger</div>');
$('.widebox-middle').after('<div class="widebox-bottom"></div>');
```

Comment: except your selectors for the widebox-middle should be `.widebox-middle` rather than `#widebox-middle` (you need to select by class rather than id)

Answer (score 2):

the `.before` and `.after` methods need to describe a fully defined part of the DOM tree - that is, each call *must* contain both opening and closing tags - these methods add *elements*, not raw html, so any malformed/incomplete html you pass in with any one statement will be converted to something valid...

Check out the `.wrap()` method - this is what you need

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 2):

`.before()` and `.after()` insert elements, not strings. An unclosed `<div>` is not a complete element, so it's automatically closed. What you want is to use the [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function to wrap your new `<div>` around the table. E.g.:

```
$('#Table3').wrap('<div class="widebox-middle" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `.wrap()` the table with those divs. But in this case, I'd prefer to
take the table out of the DOM, create the new DOM structure and insert it back, like:

```
var myTable   = $('#Table3'),
    root      = myTable.parent(),
    DOMStruct = $('<div class="widebox"><div class="widebox-header">Opret/rediger bruger</div><div class="widebox-middle"></div><div class="widebox-bottom"></div></div>');

myTable.detach();

DOMStruct.find('.widebox-middle').append(myTable);
root.append(DOMStruct);
```